# Aruino RTC using rtclib not understanding functions

Tags: rtc

I am missing something fundamental using RTClib.
When I use the rtc.adjust function to change the time in the RTC, I cannot get the updated time from the RTC, just increments a fixed time. I have searched for examples for what I need, and the same few samples of code keep getting quoted.

I want my code to set the RTC at compile to the system time, which it does, 
then in the Loop I want to increment the hour.  In reality I will use a button for this, but for now I am just trying to understand how DateTime now = rtc.now and rtc.adjust work.  How to write to the RTC, how to read it back. I am missing something regarding these variables.

Two version of my code.  One with output showing the clock working, and one where the output is static, just increments the hour.

**This one works:**

```
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <Wire.h>
int ArduinoHour;
int ArduinoMin;
int ArduinoSec;
RTC_DS1307 rtc;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(250000);
  Wire.begin();  //sets up the I2C
  rtc.begin();   //initializes the I2C to the RTC

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
    if (rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC IS running!");
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }
}
void loop()
{
  DateTime now = rtc.now(); // pings RTC and loads time info into the now variable.

  ArduinoHour = now.hour();
  ArduinoMin = now.minute();
  ArduinoSec = now.second();

  Serial.print("AT TOP");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("RTC Time");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("Arduino Time");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(ArduinoHour, DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(ArduinoMin, DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(ArduinoSec, DEC);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  //RTC increments when these are commented out. Does not when active
  //ArduinoHour = ArduinoHour +1;
  //rtc.adjust(DateTime(now.year(),now.month(),now.day(),ArduinoHour,ArduinoMin,ArduinoSec));

}
```

Here is the output.  Looks fine:

```
RTC IS running!
AT TOP
RTC Time
11:38:3

Arduino Time
11:38:3

AT TOP
RTC Time
11:38:5

Arduino Time
11:38:5

AT TOP
RTC Time
11:38:7

Arduino Time
11:38:7

AT TOP
RTC Time
11:38:9

Arduino Time
11:38:9
```

***This one does not Work:***
Now I try to simply increment variable ArduinoHour and then write it to the RTC using rtc.adjust. ***The only change are the two lines at the bottom are uncommented.***

```
#include <RTClib.h>    //https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/understanding-the-code
#include <Wire.h>

int ArduinoHour;
int ArduinoMin;
int ArduinoSec;

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(250000);
  Wire.begin();  //sets up the I2C
  rtc.begin();   //initializes the I2C to the RTC

  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
    if (rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC IS running!");
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }
}

void loop()
{
  DateTime now = rtc.now(); // pings RTC and loads time info into the now variable.

  ArduinoHour = now.hour();
  ArduinoMin = now.minute();
  ArduinoSec = now.second();

  Serial.print("AT TOP");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("RTC Time");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("Arduino Time");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(ArduinoHour, DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(ArduinoMin, DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(ArduinoSec, DEC);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  //RTC increments when these are commented out
  ArduinoHour = ArduinoHour +1;
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(now.year(),now.month(),now.day(),ArduinoHour,ArduinoMin,ArduinoSec));

}
```

Here is the output, RTC time is not changing. I know I am doing something basically wrong with how I am updating the variables writing/reading from the RTC.  Can't figure it out.

```
RTC IS running!
AT TOP
RTC Time
11:41:54

Arduino Time
11:41:54

AT TOP
RTC Time
12:41:54

Arduino Time
12:41:54

AT TOP
RTC Time
13:41:54

Arduino Time
13:41:54

AT TOP
RTC Time
14:41:54

Arduino Time
14:41:54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "RTC time is not changing" you mean minutes and seconds frozen at the same value, then this is entirely of your doing.

Your sketch spends 99% of the time between the initial `rtc.now()` request

```
 DateTime now = rtc.now(); // pings RTC and loads time info into the now variable.
```

and the final `rtc.adjust()` call

```
rtc.adjust(DateTime(now.year(),now.month(),now.day(),ArduinoHour,ArduinoMin,ArduinoSec));
```

This period is the period when your RTC is supposed to be "ticking", progressing forward.

But you actually store the original minutes and seconds values in `ArduinoMin` and `ArduinoSec` at the beginning of this period. And later, at the end of this period, you bash these values back into the clock. By doing this you forcefully *erase* whatever progress the clock made between these two lines. No wonder your minutes and second do not change.

This problem actually has no perfect solution. `RTC_DS1307` class (and, I suspect, the underlying RTC hardware) provide no means to change just the hours value without disrupting minutes and seconds. When you call `adjust()`, you have to set everything, which means that you will always somehow "disrupt" the whole clock.

In your sketch you can *minimize* the adverse effects by re-requesting the minutes and seconds values right before doing `adjust()`:

```
//RTC increments when these are commented out
ArduinoHour = ArduinoHour +1;
now = rtc.now(); 
rtc.adjust(DateTime(now.year(), now.month(), now.day(), ArduinoHour, now.minute(), now.second()));
```

Note, that I'm using your updated `ArduinoHour` values, but everything else comes from a just-refreshed `now` object.

This is still not perfect, since it still suffers from a race condition against a real-time clock, but it is better than what you had originally.

Comment: @ AnT -  Thank you.  That perfectly explains it.

Comment: @AnT, there is a suggested edit, which moves `ArduinoHour = ArduinoHour +1;` after `now = rtc.now();`. should it be accepted?

Comment: @Juraj: I don't see why. The whole idea of the workaround is to place the second `now = rtc.now();` call **as close as possible** to the `rtc.adjust` call - in order to minimize the time "lost" between these actions. Moving the `ArduinoHour = ArduinoHour + 1;` after `now = rtc.now();` (for what reason?) goes against that idea.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. My edits has nothing useful, sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of `ajust` method:

```
void RTC_DS1307::adjust(const DateTime& dt) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307_ADDRESS);
  Wire._I2C_WRITE((byte)0); // start at location 0
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.second()));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.minute()));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.hour()));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(0));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.day()));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.month()));
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(dt.year() - 2000));
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

You can write new `Hour` value directly to the clock without erasing other clock data:

```
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307_ADDRESS);
  Wire._I2C_WRITE((byte)2); // Hour location
  Wire._I2C_WRITE(bin2bcd(ArduinoHour));
  Wire.endTransmission();
```